# Simple Question - Is it possible to Edit SQL Tables from SharePoint form

Tags: sql, database-connection, crud

The title about says it all.

I've developed in Access for 20+ years. I've held off learning SharePoint because everything I've read seems to indicate restrictions on true data management.

So... here are my basic questions:

1. Is it possible to Edit data in SQL, SQL Azure, or mySQL from a SharePoint form.
2. Does SharePoint designer 2013 have the capabilities to do serious form building (main form, subforms, command buttons, combo boxes for filtering records, etc...)?

I know SharePoint is a "work in progress" and that Access is a mature product. But, I really don't feel as though I can recommend that my clients use it for anything more than simple data entry.

**Is SharePoint advancing enough that I can connect a form to a robust SQL database, bind forms to specific tables and allow for CRUD data interaction?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, through Business Connectivity Services (BCS). You will need to set up an External Content Type (ECT), which will be used to pull in tables into SharePoint for manipulation. If I were going to go the first route, I'd say use REST API, build a custom form and you can use GETs and POSTs just like a regular SharePoint list.

SharePoint Designer is the tool you will use to start with BCS and getting an ECT designed and deployed to your environment and to a specific site. There are commands in there to filter in/out specific records. You need to build out the custom form yourself, unless you want to use an OOB form from SharePoint. Once you created the ECT and the list, go to add a record, or edit a record. These will be the OOB forms. If they aren't to your liking, you need to develop a custom form.

Another route besides a custom form would be to connect it to InfoPath. See this article: [Infopath 2010 designing external list forms](https://claytoncobb.com/2009/10/28/infopath-2010-designing-external-list-forms/)

Here are a few links to get you started:

[Business Connectivity Services](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/business-connectivity-services-in-sharepoint)

[External Content Types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/administration/deploy-an-on-premises-solution)

[REST API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/jj860569%28v=office.15%29)

Comment: Thanks for jumping in here... I do appreciate it. All in all - I'm a self learner and I don't mind digging in. But, here is my current situation: 

- I'm self-employed, so I only subscribed to SharePoint online 
- I downloaded SharePoint Designer 
- I've tried setting up a Data Base Connection to my own mySQL database, but am running into errors. 
- Upon research I found I had to set up an External Content Type and got the following error message: The Business Data Connectivity Metadata Store is currently unavailable
- So ... to resolve this will I be required to purchase more product????

Comment: follow this guide for sharepoint online: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-Business-Connectivity-Service-Applications-2ced10aa-db9a-4828-a7a5-e47a57c3a823

Comment: Thank you - I will definitely go through this information.